# Can't access bios on Sumsung np 900 x3c

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, uefi

Can't access UEFI setup after installing linux. 
My steps were.

- Go to the EFI setup program (firmware) turn off fast boot and secure boot.
- Choose CSM only.
  Then I was able to boot from USB flashdrive.
- I remove all windows partitions and install elementary os.

Right now I can access firmware or choose boot device. On startup I have Samsung logo and a title at the bottom "F2-Setup F4-Recovery".
But any of F buttons doesn't doo anything. I just see grub page with elementary os.

Comment: IIRc some Sansung devices had their UEFI setup program depending on the EFI partition on disk. If you removed that then the setup is gone. (at least until you reinstall it on a GPT formatted disk with a EFI system partition)

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

- Before the power comes on. Press and hold the F2 button. Do not let up, then press on.
- Download the last bios update from Samsung Official Site.
- Remove the battery and hold the ON button for 1-2 min.
- The last option to remove the CMOS battery, wait for 1 min then replace it again.

[image]

Comment: BTW I has a pinhole to unplug battery.

Comment: Okay check this out "http://superuser.com/questions/290132/how-to-force-power-off-of-a-samsung-series-9-laptop"

Comment: Well, nothing worked(I haven't tried the lat one), So I think it's as @Hennes said Samsung fail with booting system

Comment: For that I suggest to update your BIOS at the bingeing that's will build BIOS files again

Comment: Can I update BIOS with Linux?

Comment: Yup check this link https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Flashing_BIOS_from_Linux